# Angular : I want to create a hide and show option for logged in user to hide and show their account details

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to create a hide and show option for logged in user to hide and show their account details. Clicking on a setting icon would open a popups with their account details. A hide/Show option would hide the data from the table. This should hide the data even after user logged out and logged back in until they click show. Here are the angular html and .ts code.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card ">
        <div class="card-header ">
          Bank Accounts <span style="float: right;cursor: pointer;"><i class="  fa fa-cogs"
              (click)="showCards()"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body " *ngIf="showCard">
          <h5 class="card-title">TOTAL Assets</h5>
          <p>{{users.account[0].balance | currency}}</p>
          <span class="text-center"><i>{{month}} {{day}}, {{year}}</i></span>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" style="float: right;"><i class=" text-white "
              (click)="getTrans()">Details</i></button><br><br>
          <hr>
          <h5 class="card-title">TOTAL Liability</h5>
          <p>{{users.account[0].balance | currency}}</p>
          <span class="text-center"><i>{{month}} {{day}}, {{year}}</i></span>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" style="float: right;"><i class=" text-white ">Details</i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div *ngIf="isClicked">
        <table class="table table-info table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>

              <th scope="col">Date</th>
              <th scope="col">Transaction Number</th>
              <th scope="col">medium</th>
              <th scope="col">Transaction Type</th>
              <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let t of account[0].transaction">
              <th scope="row">{{t.dot | date}}</th>
              <td>{{t.tnumber}}</td>
              <td>{{t.medium}}</td>
              <td>{{t.tType}}</td>
              <td>{{t.amount | currency}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <button class="btn btn-secondary"><i (click)="getBalance()">Chart</i></button>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="isChart">
        <div *ngIf="chart">
          <div class="chartjs-container">
            <canvas id="canvas">{{chart}}</canvas>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="card ">
        <div class="card-header ">
          Settings <span style="float: right;cursor: pointer;"><i class="  fa fa-cogs" (click)="showSet()"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body " *ngIf="settings">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Account, Balance, User } from '../_models';
import { UserService } from '../_services';
import { ChartDataSets, ChartType, ChartOptions } from 'chart.js';
import { Label } from 'ng2-charts';
import * as Chart from 'chart.js';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-account-balance',
  templateUrl: './account-balance.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account-balance.component.css']
})
export class AccountBalanceComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() users: User;
  date = null;
  day = null;
  month = null;
  year = null;
  ac:number;
  account:Account;
  isClicked:boolean=false;
  isChart:boolean=false;
  chart:any=[];
  showCard:boolean;
  showLoan:boolean;
  showInsurance:boolean;
  settings:boolean;

  value=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
  constructor(private service:UserService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.account=new Account(); 
    this.date = new Date();
    this.day = this.date.getDate();
    this.month = (this.date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' }));
    this.year = this.date.getFullYear();
    
    this.ac=this.value.account[0].accountNumber;  
    // this.barChartData=this.account[0].total

  }
  getTrans(){
    this.isClicked=!this.isClicked;
    this.service.getTran(this.ac).subscribe(
      data => {
     this.account[0]=data;
    //  this.balancechart=this.account.amount.amount
    
      
  },error=>{
      console.log(error);
  });


  }
  getBalance(){
   
    this.isChart=!this.isChart;
    this.service.getTran(this.ac).subscribe(
      data => {
     this.account[0]=data;
    //  this.balancechart=this.account.amount.amount;
     console.log(this.account[0].total);
     let balancechart=data['total'].map(res=>res.amount);
     let balanceData=data['total'].map(res=>res.date);

     let dates=[];
     balanceData.forEach(res=>{
       let jsdate=new Date(res);
       dates.push(jsdate.toLocaleString('en',{year:'numeric',month:'short',day:'numeric'}))
     })
     console.log(dates);
     this.chart=new Chart('canvas',{
       type:'line',
       data:{
         labels:dates,
         datasets:[
           {
             data:balancechart,
             borderColor:'#3cba9f',
             fill:false
           }
         ]
       },
       options:{
         legend:{
           display:false
         },
         scales:{
           xAxes:[{display:true}],
           yAxes:[{display:true}]
         }
       }


    })

      
  },error=>{
      console.log(error);
  });

  }
  showCards(){
    this.showCard=!this.showCard;
    this.isClicked=false;
    this.isChart=false;
  }
  showCard2(){
    this.showLoan=!this.showLoan;
  }
  showIns(){
    this.showInsurance=!this.showInsurance;
  }
  showSet(){
    this.settings=!this.settings;
  }

}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to save it to the database or at least localStorage

Comment: if you can could you tell me How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

*you can declare Boolean variable for this and by default is true to show information when you click on setting icon it hit the hideShow function in typescript and check the value of show and use the show variable in angular template *

```js
var show:bolean = true ;

hideShow(){

if(show ==  true){
this.show = false;
}else if(show ==  false){
this.show = true;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body " [hidden] ="show">
          <h5 class="card-title">TOTAL Assets</h5>
          <p>{{users.account[0].balance | currency}}</p>
          <span class="text-center"><i>{{month}} {{day}}, {{year}}</i></span>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" style="float: right;"><i class=" text-white "
              (click)="getTrans()">Details</i></button><br><br>
          <hr>
          <h5 class="card-title">TOTAL Liability</h5>
          <p>{{users.account[0].balance | currency}}</p>
          <span class="text-center"><i>{{month}} {{day}}, {{year}}</i></span>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" style="float: right;"><i class=" text-white ">Details</i>                 </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That wouldnt save the state if logged out and logged back in? if its hidden logging back in would keep the content hidden?

Comment: @ashrafulIslam please store in session